# WP7: can I access items on mainpage.xaml from app.xaml.cs?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to preload some setting on mainpage.xaml but only app is launched one time.
I know I should use Application_Launching event in app.xaml but How can I set first value of my textbox on mainpage.xaml?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IsolatedStorage for your textbox. [Tombstoning sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I thought Isolatedstorage is like notepad of windowsphone where i can store some data but not initially values. maybe my explanation was very unclear. simply a sample, I want to set my datepicker initially take 1 day later than today.  I did that first just like this

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        dtpDate.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

    }
```

but then I realized if user tries to change datapickers value, it causes page loaded again and it takes inital value. secondly, I learnt I should use Application_Launching event in app.xaml but I couldnt figure out how to set this below from app.xaml

dtpDate.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

thanks for your help